# How to update and insert a new record on when matched condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, scd2

I have written a stored procedure in SQL Server. Basically it tries to handle SCD2. Three things am trying to do:

1. When not matched by target, insert the record
2. When not matched by source, inactivate the active record(update)
3. When matched, update the active record flag to N

These 3 scenarios are being properly handled.

My problem is when matched I need to insert a new record as well in source. I have some article suggesting to use `$output` clause and do insert on top of `MERGE`; I tried it but I get this error:

> Msg 356, Level 16, State 1, Procedure myscd2, Line 17
>   The target table 'dbo.dimproducts' of the INSERT statement cannot be on either side of a (primary key, foreign key) relationship when the FROM clause contains a nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement. Found reference constraint 'FK_FactSalesOrders_DimProducts'.

Please see my code below and let me know, what can I do to resolve this issue:

```
begin
    insert into dbo.dimproducts(ProductID, ProductName, StandardListPrice, ProductSubCategoryID, ProductSubCategoryName, ProductCategoryID, ProductCategoryName, active_flag)   
        select 
            productid, name, ListPrice, 
            productsubcategoryid, ProductSubCategoryName,
            ProductCategoryID, ProductCategoryName, Active_Flag 
        from
            (merge dbo.dimproducts as tgt
             using AdventureWorks_Basics.dbo.Products as src on (tgt.productid = src.productid)
             when matched and src.name != tgt.productname and tgt.active_flag = 'Y'
                then 
                   update set tgt.active_flag = 'N'
             when not matched by target
                then 
                   insert(ProductID, ProductName, StandardListPrice, ProductSubCategoryID, ProductSubCategoryName, ProductCategoryID, ProductCategoryName, active_flag)
                   values (src.productid, src.name, src.listprice, 100, 'ABC', 101, coalesce(src.productline, 'XYZ'), 'Y')
             when not matched by source
                then 
                   update set tgt.active_flag = 'N'
             OUTPUT $action AS Action, src.productid, src.name, src.listprice, 100 as productsubcategoryid, 'ABC' as ProductSubCategoryName, 101 as ProductCategoryID, coalesce(src.productline, 'XYZ') as ProductCategoryName, 'Y' as Active_Flag) AS MergeOutput
        where
            MergeOutput.Action = 'UPDATE';
```

Comment: Avoid using Merge statement, the reason I suggested this, have a  read of this article [`Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) , 13 active bugs with this merge statement. Break the merge statement down to good old inserts and updates and wrap them in one transaction.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limitation on the `OUTPUT` clause that the target cannot have a FOREIGN KEY constraint, or be referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint. Hence the error you are getting.

However you can do the following, insert data into temp table from output clause and then select from temp table to insert into your target table.

**Warning** I would still advise you to avoid using `MERGE` statement and read the article for the reasons.

```
CREATE TABLE #dimproducts (
 Act                        VARCHAR(10)
,ProductID                  INT
,ProductName                VARCHAR(100)
,StandardListPrice          INT
,ProductSubCategoryID       INT
,ProductSubCategoryName     VARCHAR(100)
,ProductCategoryID          INT
,ProductCategoryName        VARCHAR(100)
,active_flag                VARCHAR(1));

merge dbo.dimproducts as tgt
    using  AdventureWorks_Basics.dbo.Products as src    on (tgt.productid = src.productid)

when matched and src.name != tgt.productname and tgt.active_flag = 'Y'then 
    update set tgt.active_flag = 'N'

when not matched by target then 
    insert(ProductID,ProductName,StandardListPrice,ProductSubCategoryID,ProductSubCategoryName,ProductCategoryID,ProductCategoryName,active_flag)
    values(src.productid,src.name,src.listprice,100,'ABC',101,coalesce(src.productline,'XYZ'),'Y')

when not matched by source then
    update set tgt.active_flag = 'N'

    OUTPUT $action AS Action, src.productid,src.name,src.listprice,100 as productsubcategoryid,'ABC' as ProductSubCategoryName
                    ,101 as ProductCategoryID,coalesce(src.productline,'XYZ') as ProductCategoryName,'Y' as Active_Flag
    INTO #dimproducts (Act,ProductID,ProductName,StandardListPrice,ProductSubCategoryID,ProductSubCategoryName,ProductCategoryID,ProductCategoryName,active_flag);

INSERT INTO dbo.dimproducts (productid,name,ListPrice,productsubcategoryid,ProductSubCategoryName,ProductCategoryID,ProductCategoryName,Active_Flag)
select productid,name,ListPrice,productsubcategoryid,ProductSubCategoryName,ProductCategoryID,ProductCategoryName,Active_Flag 
FROM #dimproducts
WHERE Act = 'UPDATE';
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/MERGE/73805/

**Slowly changing dimensions using T-SQL MERGE**
By Adam Aspin, 2011/06/20
See section: *Type 2 SCD - Keep a history of previous attributes as separate records, indicate the dates they were valid, and flag the currently valid record*

its basically M.Ali's answer with a ton more information as well as info on SCD 1, 3, and 4: